# Detect when gradle is run inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I want to switch my active build-type based on if gradle is being run inside Android Studio or from command line on our ci servers.

We have a separate project (in a separate repository) which we want to include into our project, but only if open it in Android Studio.

Is there any environment variable set by Android Studio which we can use for this? Also, can you select a build-type from gradle?

Comment: Why don't you creat a new `task` for CI builder command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AndroidStudio 2.x you can do this in your build.gradle:

```
def sysprops = System.getProperties()
if (sysprops['idea.platform.prefix'] != null) {
    // Built from AndroidStudio
} else {
    // Built from command line
}
```